# Could the following code produce a crash on older devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have this bit of code relating to my in app purchases for an `SKProductRequest`:

```
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:...
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
    [request release];
```

One of my users is getting a crash on an iPod4 and I think it might be from this, however, all other devices are able to run this code OK. Should request be saved in a property while its loading, could that be the issue? I would think with [request start], that request would be retained somewhere else.

Here is the crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3275229e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a3c597a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3269ce88 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 160
3   AppsHappens Lite                        0x000e43ac 0xd8000 + 50092
4   StoreKit                        0x3450c22e __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke_0 + 378
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7dd11a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7dc4b2 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7dddc6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 222
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32725f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32698eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32698d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
11  GraphicsServices                0x362492e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
12  UIKit                           0x345ae2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
13  AppsHappens Lite        0x000e3a8e 0xd8000 + 47758
14  AppsHappens Lite        0x000dadb4 0xd8000 + 11700
```

Updated: A lot of folks below are saying that it's an array out of bounds error and I think they're right. Strange thing is though, it appears the product request is coming back successfully, and it's called ing `[self loadFullVersionPrice]` which simply extracts the price for one of my products. When it tries to retrieve the Full Version product from the `products` array, I think that's when it crashes. Is it possible the app store would only return some of my products and not all of them? Or some issue with an iPod4?

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    self.products = response.products;

    if (self.products)
    {
        [self loadFullVersionPrice];
    }
}

- (void) loadFullVersionPrice
{
    SKProduct *product = [[self.products objectAtIndex:[self.products count]-1] retain];

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    self.fullVersionPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    [numberFormatter release];
    [product release];
}
```

Also, the iPod Touch 4 in question is jail broken.

Comment: What is "self"?  The SKProductRequest doesn't retain its delegate, so if "self" isn't retained somewhere then the SKProductRequest might call back into a dealloc'd object and crash.  Try to get a crash log from your user, or look at your iTunes Connect crash reports and see if you track down where the crash is occurring.

Comment: Don't guess, store it yourself to be sure. Also, get the crash log from your user.

Comment: It's possible there's a timing related bug which is manifested on slower devices. It could also be an OS difference. For the above code, seems like you should definitely call `-stop` after calling `-start` and before `-release`, no?

Comment: @wain - updated with crash log

Comment: @NicholasHart - updated with crash log, is it possible to tell from that have no clue

Comment: @nielsbot - it does seem funny, prob like Wain says should store it in a property just to be sure

Comment: You need to symbolic ate the crash log and it will tell you what file and line the exception was on.

Comment: if request.delegate isn't retained, you can use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` to effectively add a retained property for delegate to `SKProductsRequest`. You could also perhaps make a wrapper object that has a reference to an enclosed `SKProductsRequest` and `delegate`

Comment: If the exception came from `-[ NSArray objectAtIndex:]` I bet it's an _index out of range_ exception

Comment: It looks like when your app is handling the StoreKit response your code is trying to access an array beyond its bounds.  Focus your efforts there.

Comment: Check the delegate method - you are most probably doing something wrong there with arrays.

Comment: @wain - going to see if he can do that thanks. updated with some new info.

Comment: @nielsbot - Think you're exactly right, updated with the code where it may be happening. Is it possible that only some of the products could be returned?

Comment: @NicholasHart - You're right, and I've updated with the code. It appears the products are being returned out of order or in complete. Is that even possible?

Comment: You can't count on any particular order that the products will be returned in.  I don't think you can guarantee any particular number of products either.  For one thing, what if one of your products hasn't been approved yet?  Or is only available in certain countries?  Or you go in to iTunes Connect and take it down?  You should never make assumptions about what data will be returned from StoreKit.  The app should look at the data that is returned and act on it accordingly.

Comment: Just a tip: I often use `if ( array.count > 0 )` instead of `if ( array )` and `if ( string.length > 0 )` instead of `if ( string )` to test for missing arrays/strings. These will catch both `nil` _and_ empty objects... (If that's what your code is tripping over.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three reasons why this was occurring:

1) The user was on a jail broken phone
2) The version of my app he was installing was an ad hoc release
3) He was trying to access in app purchase

Apparently, jail broken phones are unable to access the sandbox (which is accessed when you try to do an app purchase on an ad hoc distribution).